# Is there a way to remove certain duplicates of a list but not others?

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, tuples

So I've been working on a  a pretty complicated list that is formed from taking parts of a dictonary of tuples. here is my code.

```
 var Truth = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string, string>, bool>

         {
             {new Tuple <string,string,string>("!A","!B","!C"),false },
             {new Tuple <string,string,string>("!A","!B","C"),false },
             {new Tuple <string,string,string>("!A","B","!C"),false },
             {new Tuple <string,string,string>("!A","B","C"),false },
             {new Tuple <string,string,string>("A","!B","!C"),true },
             {new Tuple <string,string,string>("A","!B","C"),true },
             {new Tuple <string,string,string>("A","B","!C"),true },
             {new Tuple <string,string,string>("A","B","C"),true},
         };

         var trueKeyList = Truth.Where(kv => kv.Value).ToList();
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();



        Console.WriteLine("SOP is: ");
        foreach (var keyValue in trueKeyList)
        {

                Console.Write(keyValue.Key.ToString().Trim(new Char[] { ')', '(' }));
                Console.Write(" AND ");
            myList.Add(keyValue.Key.Item1);
            myList.Add(keyValue.Key.Item2);
            myList.Add(keyValue.Key.Item3);


        }
        Console.WriteLine("");


        List<string> lstStrIgnore = new List<string>() { "A!", "B!", "C!" };
        myList = myList.Distinct().Where(x => x != lstStrIgnore).ToList();
```

near the bottom you'll see my attempt to remove duplicates of A B and C but not of A! B! and C!. however this doesn't work because it says "operand != can not be applied to type string and types List" is there anyway to do this?

Comment: The `myList` does't include any item from the `lstStrIgnore` already. In case you have different inputs, then `var outputList = myList.Except(lstStrIgnore);` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myList.Distinct().Where(x => !lstStrIgnore.Contains(x));
```

Or if you want to apply your own comparer / cast to upper / lower case, etc

```
myList.Distinct().Where(x => !lstStrIgnore.Any(l => l.Equals(x)));
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the second option works. however  one more question, i may have to ask another but do you know if its possible to replace two elements in a list with one new element?

Comment: You should mark my answer as answer if it works for you then. As for your second question - If you want to replace the exact node in your list then find the elements index in the sequence, by int index = list.IndexOf(b); then use RemoveAt and Insert.